limitToLast() is not working in firebase realtime
When building a query to select the latest data in firebase, all data is selected instead of the amount specified in the argument. I noticed that this problem also exists in the first message selection. I don't know about other query parameters, I didn't use them.
export const messagesRef = ref(database, `messages/`)
export async function getMessages() {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        const data = []
        const lastMessages = query(messagesRef, limitToFirst(10))
        const snapshot = get(lastMessages).then(() => {
            Object.entries(snapshot).forEach(([key, value]) => {
                data.push({ ...value, key: key })
            })
            resolve(data)
        })
    })
}

Honestly, I don't even know what to do here. I looked at the firebase documentation, but didn't understand what I did wrong. I asked copylot and dug around in stackoverflow.

Calling get(lastMessages in your code will return at most 10 child nodes. If that is not the behavior you're seeing, edit your question to show the input you provide (so the data you query)(as JSON text, no screenshots please), and the output you get (so for example console.log the key of each child when you loop over then).

Your code accesses snapshot inside the callback, before it's even assigned. My guess is that you're seeing outdated data there, for example: the data from the previous time you assigned snapshot (my guess is: with all child data).
Your code contains a few anti-patterns too, so here how I would implement getMessages:
export async function getMessages() {
    const data = []
    const lastMessages = query(messagesRef, limitToFirst(10))
    const snapshot = await get(lastMessages);
    snapshot.forEach((child) => {
        data.push({ ...child.val(), key: child.key })
    })

    return data;
}

The changes from yours:

This code no longer depends on the snapshot value that was outside of the callback.
This code doesn't return a custom Promise, but rather uses the promise that Firebase already returns.
This code uses Firebase's built-in forEach to loop over the results, rather than Object.Entries (which knows nothing about Firebase).

